# Weiestrass M-Test Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Hi there I am struggling with the question above. I managed to prove that it converges $\mid z \mid \leq p$ using the Weierstrass M-test, with $M_{n}=\frac{z^{n}}{n(2-p)}$ followed by the ratio test.

However, I was not sure whether the series was uniformly convergent on $\mid z \mid \leq 1$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which question: (i) or (ii), or both?

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\left|\frac{z^n}{n(2+z)}\right|\le\frac{\rho^n}{n(2-\rho)}\le\rho^n,\quad\forall |z|\le\rho$$
and the geometric series $\sum \rho^n$ is convergent so we have the uniform convergence of the given series on the closed disc $\overline D(0,\rho)$.

For the second question notice that the series isn't convergent for $z=1$ so it isn't *a fortiori* uniformly convergent on $\overline D(0,1).$